# How to zoom whole RecyclerView in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, zooming

I've created a zoom function which is working zooming for `LinearLayout` and `FrameLayout` but not working for `RecyclerView`.

XML file :

```
<com.nm.esign.entities.ZoomLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/zoom_main1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fl_zoom"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_template_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"

            android:scrollbars="vertical" />


    </LinearLayout>


     </com.nm.esign.entities.ZoomLayout>
```

Main activity:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_template);

        //  prevBtn=(android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton)findViewById(R.id.btnDocumentPrev_temp);
        // nextBtn=(android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton)findViewById(R.id.btnDocumentNxt_temp);
    RecyclerView    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_template_img);

    LinearLayout    fl_zoom=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.fl_zoom)


        ZoomLayout myZoomView = new ZoomLayout(ViewTemplate.this);

      fl_zoom.addView(myZoomView); // working fine
// recyclerView.addView(myZoomView); // not working 

....................................

}
```

`ZoomLayout` class:

```
/**
 * Created by Lenovo5 on 3/16/2017.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

/**
 * Layout that provides pinch-zooming of content. This view should have exactly one child
 * view containing the content.
 */
public class ZoomLayout extends FrameLayout implements ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener {

    private enum Mode {
        NONE,
        DRAG,
        ZOOM
    }

    private static final String TAG = "ZoomLayout";
    private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1.0f;
    private static final float MAX_ZOOM = 4.0f;

    private Mode mode = Mode.NONE;
    private float scale = 1.0f;
    private float lastScaleFactor = 0f;

    // Where the finger first  touches the screen
    private float startX = 0f;
    private float startY = 0f;

    // How much to translate the canvas
    private float dx = 0f;
    private float dy = 0f;
    private float prevDx = 0f;
    private float prevDy = 0f;

    public ZoomLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        final ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, this);
        this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Log.i(TAG, "DOWN");
                        if (scale > MIN_ZOOM) {
                            mode = Mode.DRAG;
                            startX = motionEvent.getX() - prevDx;
                            startY = motionEvent.getY() - prevDy;
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == Mode.DRAG) {
                            dx = motionEvent.getX() - startX;
                            dy = motionEvent.getY() - startY;
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                        mode = Mode.ZOOM;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = Mode.DRAG;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.i(TAG, "UP");
                        mode = Mode.NONE;
                        prevDx = dx;
                        prevDy = dy;
                        break;
                }
                scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

                if ((mode == Mode.DRAG && scale >= MIN_ZOOM) || mode == Mode.ZOOM) {
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    float maxDx = (child().getWidth() - (child().getWidth() / scale)) / 2 * scale;
                    float maxDy = (child().getHeight() - (child().getHeight() / scale))/ 2 * scale;
                    dx = Math.min(Math.max(dx, -maxDx), maxDx);
                    dy = Math.min(Math.max(dy, -maxDy), maxDy);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Width: " + child().getWidth() + ", scale " + scale + ", dx " + dx
                            + ", max " + maxDx);
                    applyScaleAndTranslation();
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    // ScaleGestureDetector

    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onScaleBegin");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
        float scaleFactor = scaleDetector.getScaleFactor();
        Log.i(TAG, "onScale" + scaleFactor);
        if (lastScaleFactor == 0 || (Math.signum(scaleFactor) == Math.signum(lastScaleFactor))) {
            scale *= scaleFactor;
            scale = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scale, MAX_ZOOM));
            lastScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
        } else {
            lastScaleFactor = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onScaleEnd");
    }

    private void applyScaleAndTranslation() {
        child().setScaleX(scale);
        child().setScaleY(scale);
        child().setTranslationX(dx);
        child().setTranslationY(dy);
    }

    private View child() {
        return getChildAt(0);
    }
}
```

Error  coming for:-

```
  recyclerView.addView(myZoomView);

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.nm.esign, PID: 6028
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nm.esign/com.nm.esign.activity.ViewTemplate}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.generateDefaultLayoutParams(RecyclerView.java:3869)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4431)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4409)
    at com.nm.esign.activity.ViewTemplate.onCreate(ViewTemplate.java:112)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: According to error, it seems that you have not set `LayoutManager` to the `RecylcerView`.

Comment: requirement is , i have Recycle View which contains list of image . i want to zoom all image when zooming any one of image..

Comment: @kamlesh is ur problem solved? i am not asking about the layout manager not added thing but where you able to zoom all the images in recycler view and there is no issue in scrolling experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have this line in your code

```
LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

Comment: not working .  got error   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.findMinMaxChildLayoutPositions(RecyclerView.java:3680)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3417)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple, you can create the layout manager manager manually.

Code snippet from https://github.com/kanytu/example-parallaxrecycler/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/poliveira/apps/exampleparallaxrecycler/MainActivity.java#L24

Add this

```
LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
myRecycler.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

Comment: got error:                                                                                                                                       FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            Process: com.nm.esign, PID: 1557
                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference

Comment: I've got this error during one of my development. Have you checked that your RecyclerView in your XML files are correctly wrapped into another layout like a FrameLayout?

If not, it will crash only on a Viewpager and not on single fragment view.

Comment: yes i used inside  1. ZoomLayout 2.LinearLayout 3.FrameLayout 4.RecyclerView